# Covnert string of dd-mm-yy to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I'm using a scanner that gets details from a UK driving licence. However it returns the date as a string and most current uk driving licences are `dd-mm-yy` (16-10-10). Is there a way I can make it `dd-mm-yyyy` but with the right two numbers in front of it i.e. 16-10-2010?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `DateFormatter` from the standard library. Besides that, what about licenses before 2000?

Comment: Would it catch that as well? Obviously I don't want like `2093`

Comment: Pretty sure it's going to be written as 1993.

Comment: you can use SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: @KaranChunara Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String strDate = "16-10-10";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String s = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(s);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).